# Set image width globally for LaTeX export

Tags: org-mode, latex

I write my research notes in org-mode, and I'd like to avoid writing `#+ATTR_LaTeX: :width 5cm :placement [!htpb]` right before all of my figures, to save some time. A possible solution might be to make changes to my `.emacs` file. I'm just not sure what to add.

I have spent quite some time searching for a solution to this, but so far I haven't found one.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a remedy in some situations I'm applying org capture templates (http://orgmode.org/guide/Capture-templates.html) to insert images with all necessary attributes automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
(setq org-latex-image-default-width "5cm")
```